# How do I use the enumerate and .append functions correctly?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and this is my first attempt at making something on my own. I'm trying to make a simple program that detects when something has been written in a .txt file. Right now the first 'if' statement in my 'for' loop works, so I can do something with that. But when I want to move on to the second one, something breaks and it won't print "success2", even though the requirements within the .txt file are met. I'm not very comfortable with the .append and enumerate functions yet, so I can't see the problem on my own. Thanks to anyone who might be able to help!

```
    from win32 import win32gui
    import win32ui
    import time



    def League_Running():
    #Checks if the client is running and returns True or False
    if win32ui.FindWindow(None, "League of Legends (TM) Client"):
        return True
    else:
        print("not found")
        return False


   firstused = False 
   secondused = False

   while League_Running():
       content = []
       linenumber = {4}

       for i, note in enumerate(open(r'C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\MyNotes.txt', "r")): #Opens the .txt file
           if i in linenumber:
               if linenumber == {4} and linenumber!= None and not firstused:
                   content.append(note) #adds the line in the .txt file to the content list
                   if "test" in str(content):  #checks for a specific line in the content list
                       print("success")
                       firstused = True #so it doesnt get printed out 100x every second, will add time.sleep() later
                       linenumber = {5}
                   content.remove(note) #not sure if this is necessary?

                if linenumber == {5} and linenumber!= None and not secondused:
                    content.append(note) #pretty sure this is where it breaks

                    if "hello" in str(content):
                        print("success2")
                        secondused = True
                        linenumber = {6}
```

The contents of the .txt file:

#

2020-05-16_14-29-53_

#

test

hello

Comment: If you are using PyCharm or VSCode, I would highly recommend learning in-depth how to debug your programs. This will allow you to see the values of your variables as you progress through each step, and the issue you are facing may become more obvious.

Comment: I'm using IDLE right now, but I will look into those. Thank you!

Comment: In case you go with PyCharm, here's a useful [guide](https://realpython.com/pycharm-guide/#debugging-in-pycharm) from realpython.com